# Can I sell my business car to myself (personal)?

Tags: united-states, business, maryland, vehicle

I am seeking to change the ownership of my vehicle from my business to myself? In other words, the vehicle will no longer be used for business purposes - just for personal.
Now, my accountant mentioned that I will need to go to my local licensing authority (MVA - Maryland, in my case) and initiate the title transfer AND pay the sales tax.
The question is, how do I assess and present the market value on the basis of which the state's 6% sales tax will be computed?

Comment: Have you asked MVA?